# Can't delete one event from series in calendar.app from a google calendar

Tags: calendar, ical, google-calendar

I have a series of events in a Google calendar that's connected to Calendar.app. When I try to delete one event (I confirm in the prompt that I want to delete the one event) in the series it reappears immediately.

How can I remove just one instance without it reincarnating?

Comment: Does the answer and comment provided help you narrow down your problem? Others seem to have similar issues so it would be nice to figure out whether your calendar has some bad entries or it's a bug / known problem we could document for people.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the account using CalDAV, as Google recommends? It could of course be a bug in Calendar.app, but I would make sure that the recommended settings are used. See here:
https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/99358?hl=en

Indeed, as rob speculated, Google doesn't provide Exchange ActiveSync any more for new devices:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2716936?hl=en

However, that doesn't seem to be the reason for the problem in question. For me nothing was synced an a new iPhone with an Exchange type Google account, and thus, there were no events to be deleted either. I switched to using CalDAV, which works fine.

Comment: I would also recommend making a new test google account with a very simple calendar. Maybe two events, one today and another repeating to ensure it's not just a bug in the software. If you can reproduce it on a simple test case, you'll know you can report it and probably get resolution from either Google or Apple.